# Is there a way to count instances from a class?

Tags: javascript, class, instance

I need to keep track of how many instances of a class have been created, from within the said class. I need every instance natively to know 'which one' it is.

The only way I could think of was to use global variables but... there may be a better way.

Here is what I want to avoid:

```
class MyClass {
    this.instanceId = (window.instanceCount == undefined) ? 0 : window.instanceCount + 1;
    window.instanceCount = this.instanceId;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Use a class variable rather than a global variable, and increment it in the constructor.

Comment: Just exchange `window` for a better suited object… And no need to make it a global variable, any variable outside the constructor scope will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can statically add a counter to your "class". Here I use a symbol to prevent names collision. Note that I check whether you use `Burrito` as a function or a class prior to incrementing the counter.

```js
function Burrito() {
  if (this instanceof Burrito) {
    Burrito[Burrito.counterName]++;
  }
}

Burrito.counterName = Symbol();
Burrito[Burrito.counterName] = 0;
Burrito.count = () => Burrito[Burrito.counterName];

new Burrito(); // 1
new Burrito(); // 2
Burrito();     // skipped
new Burrito(); // 3

console.log(Burrito.count());
```

Comment: Thanks, it's actually the only cross-browser valid answer. I'm having a hard time understanding the "Prototype[Prototype.property]" syntax though. How does that make a static property?

Comment: Please note that I don't actually use the prototype in this answer. The property is set on the function itself and not on its prototype.

Comment: Right :-) What does Function[Function.property] mean, though? It does works but I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: This is the same as accessing a property. If you know the name of the property, you'd simply do `obj.foo`. However if the property name is given to you, you need to evaluate it e.g. `var key = 'some-random-string'; obj[key]` which is different than `obj['key']` or `obj.key`. In the last two examples you access a property which name is literally `'key'`. In my answer I have used a `Symbol()` to prevent name collision, since I don't know what the symbol would be I need to save it and evaluate it when accessing the counter property. (The symbol is the name given to the counter property).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `static` property and increase it in the `constructor()`

```js
class MyClass{
  static count = 0;
  constructor(){
    this.instanceId = ++MyClass.count;
  }
}
let x = new MyClass();
let y = new MyClass();

console.log(MyClass.count) //2

console.log(x.instanceId); //1
console.log(y.instanceId); //2
```

Comment: Except that's not valid ES8.

Comment: @Bergi Why it's not valid ES8

Comment: Class fields are still a proposal only. You should mention that when posting answers with code that is using them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary for the property to be in the global scope:

```
class MyClass {
    static count = 0;
    instanceId = MyClass.count++;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JavaScript

Comment: @Bergi it is valid.

Comment: I'm getting a `SyntaxError: bad method definition` in Firefox. Classes (in the current standard) can only contain method (and getter/setter) definitions.

Comment: @Bergi Because your browser hasn't implemented this syntax. Download chrome - or transpile.

Comment: Chrome [implementing non-standard features](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6001727933251584) and enabling them by default doesn't make this valid JavaScript. Don't take them for granted, and mention in your answer when you're using any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily simplify class instances.

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 10;
        this.b = 20;
    }
    m1() {
        this.c = 30;
    }
}

let obj = new Test()
count = Object.keys(obj).length;
console.log(count) //-------------------2
obj.m1();
count = Object.keys(obj).length;
console.log(count) //-------------------3
```